# winapi: child window grab focus when and only when mouse over it

Tags: windows, winapi, mouseover, setfocus

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Scrolling the Window Under the Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256016/scrolling-the-window-under-the-mouse), because I cannot tolerate the mouse wheel going to any arbitrary window under the cursor.  Also, I actually want focus on this one particular window, as I also want keystrokes to go there, but only when the mouse is over the window.  The other question is for someone who wants mouse wheel input to go to the moused-over window, does not care about focus, and can tolerate this behavior for every window or control processed by the message loop.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  I'm writing a win32 application in plain c.  There is the main window, and a child window contained within that.  What I want is for the child window to grab focus any time the mouse cursor is in the client area of that window, so that the child window can process mouse wheel movement during that time.  But once the cursor leaves the client area, I want the child to relinquish focus, and stop processing the mouse wheel.  The code in the Windows Procedure below does the job, but seems clumsy.  It grabs focus when the mouse crosses the child window border (which I assume is a non-client area), and immediately issues WM_NCMOUSELEAVE when the mouse enters the client area.  Then it grabs focus again, and keeps it until the mouse crosses the window border again.  Ideally, I'd like to grab focus just once when the mouse enters the client area, and keep focus until the mouse leaves the client area.  Any ideas?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DisplayWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        // Set focus to self when mouse enters display window
        // client area.
        // must have focus so that can see mouse wheel
        // TrackMouseEvent() will generate WM_NCMOUSELEAVE when mouse exits
        // Reason for checking focus first is so that won't have  multiple
        // calls to TrackMouseEvent()
        if ((GetFocus() != hWndDisplay)) {
            SetFocus(hWndDisplay);
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE | TME_NONCLIENT;
            tme.hwndTrack = hWndDisplay;
            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCMOUSELEAVE:
        SetFocus(NULL);  // give up focus
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        debugInt = (short) HIWORD(wParam);  // wheel movement in high word
        debugInt = debugInt / WHEEL_DELTA;
        debugInt = (short) LOWORD(lParam); // mouse x coord
        debugInt = (short) HIWORD(lParam); // mouse y coord
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even if this is just for debugging, don't use `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` (as explicitly spelled out in the documentation for [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617.aspx)). Use [GET_X_LPARAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632654.aspx) and [GET_Y_LPARAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632655.aspx) instead.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks.  Close to a duplicate, but I absolutely don't want the mouse wheel doing to any window that the cursor is over, only that one window.  In some cases, I want the wheel to go to a control that has focus, but is not necessarily moused over.  And good point about GET_X_LPARAM, I'll make that change now.

Comment: Why create a non-standard UI for your users? You (and they) can turn off the troublesome mousewheel behaviour through the control panel if desired.

Comment: @JonathanPotter This is for an oscilloscope software, where a very common action will be to point at a particular point on the screen, and zoom in on the data.  The paradigm should be familiar to users - for example, Google Maps employs it.  Like Google Maps, I want the mouse wheel behavior when the cursor is over the displayed data, and don't want it when the cursor is elsewhere.  When the cursor is elsewhere, the mouse wheel goes to the focused control or window - a well-understood Windows paradigm.

Comment: @roderickyoung You mentioned "Google Maps". But the way Google Maps works is related to the duplicate post. You don't need to watch `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_NCMOUSELEAVE`, you don't need to programmatically change window focus. You only need to watch `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, then check `WindowFromPoint` to see if you should or shouldn't process the wheel message.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani re: Google Maps, I was just responding to the comment that suggested my UI would be non-standard.  I do share the zoom paradigm with Maps, but with an important difference from the supposed duplicate.  If the user clicks on one of the trackbars in my program, I want that trackbar to have focus and maintain focus, getting the mousewheel events even if the cursor is no longer on that control (assuming, of course, that the cursor is not in the client area of the display window).

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I do acknowledge that what I want could be done in the message loop, but it would require at least WindowFromPoint() and determining which window had focus.  Seems not worth it, since that would be duplicating the job that Windows will do anyway by default. I was hoping there might be a simple and standard way to do what I want, but it looks like the code above may be the simplest.  Thanks for your input, anyway.

Comment: There are two answers in duplicate topic, I recommend the [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33553452/4603670) which  doesn't change the message loop.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks for your patience and kindness.  Tried that but the other solution doesn't quite work for me, because it relies on the parent window having focus.  If another control in the parent window has focus (say, a trackbar), the parent never sees the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message, and cannot forward it to the display child window.  It could be made to work, but I would have to capture all WM_MOUSEWHEEL always, and micro-manage forwarding to every control.  Plus, I would still have to forward keystrokes to the child, which is what focus does anyway.  It's ok; I'll manage.

Comment: Okay, I reversed my vote. Although I still prefer not changing the focus. By the way, I believe the issue has been fixed in Windows 10, the mouse wheel works the way you expect it to work without making any changes.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Good to hear Microsoft fixed it!  My app must run all the way back to Win XP unfortunately (yes, I know, not supported by MS). Thanks again.